# Determine the position of an element in an IQueryable

Tags: c#, linq, iqueryable

I have a IQueryable which is ordered by some condition. 
Now I want to know the position of a particular element in that IQueryable.
Is there a linq expression to get that.
Say for example there are 10 elements in the IQueryable and the 6th element matches a condition, I want to get the number 6.

Comment: Don't you want to get the number 5 if the 6th element matches? Normally the first element has index 0, second has index 1, etc.

Comment: yes thats what I wanted and the below answer works fine

Answer (score 16, accepted):

First select each item with its index, then filter the items, and finally extract the original index:

```
var result = orderedList
    .Select((x, i) => new { Item = x, Index = i })
    .Where(itemWithIndex => itemWithIndex.Item.StartsWith("g"))
    .FirstOrDefault();

int index= -1;
if (result != null)
    index = result.Index;
```

Test bed:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var orderedList = new List<string>
        {
            "foo", "bar", "baz", "qux", "quux",
            "corge", "grault", "garply", "waldo",
            "fred", "plugh", "xyzzy", "thud"
        }.OrderBy(x => x);

        // bar, baz, corge, foo, fred, garply, grault,
        // plugh, quux, qux, thud, waldo, xyzzy
        // Find the index of the first element beginning with 'g'.

        var result = orderedList
            .Select((x, i) => new { Item = x, Index = i })
            .Where(itemWithIndex => itemWithIndex.Item.StartsWith("g"))
            .FirstOrDefault();

        int index= -1;
        if (result != null)
            index = result.Index;

        Console.WriteLine("Index: " + index);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Index: 5
```

Comment: Is this solution generates SQL for all operation or it selects all items of IQueryable and only after that makes operation in memory?

Answer (score 2):

You could use something like `query.TakeWhile(x => !matchesCondition(x)).Count()`, though that has the effect of enumerating the preceding values, which may not be what you want.

Comment: You have to enumerate through those preceding values anyway, haven't you?

Comment: Interesting solution. It would be OK to enumerate the preceding values if it were a memory object, but not for a DB. Note that if the element is not in the list, this function returns the length of the list. Normally you would expect such functions to return -1 or perhaps null.

Comment: @Mark Byers: I read the question's phrasing as implying that the desired element was known to be present, and only the position was desired; and the DB scenario was indeed my concern about enumerating.

In practice I suspect that doing this to an IQueryable is unwise, but as a quick hack this approach is at least succinct and understandable.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the verson of the "Where" function that incldes the collection index as a parameter to the predicate function.  See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549418.aspx) for more info.

```
var result = Enumerable.Range(0, 10).Where((x, i) => i == 6);
```

The version could result in an empty list if there isn't a 6th element. Also this doesn't evaluate the where clause until you iterate over the result.