# Getting next and previous on a Queryable

Tags: c#, linq

Yo what up gangstas?

I have the following code which seems to return `null` always.

```
    public static T GetNext<T>(this IQueryable<T> list, T current)
    {
        try
        {
            return list.SkipWhile(x => !x.Equals(current)).Skip(1).First();
        }
        catch
        {
            return default(T);
        }
    }

    public static T GetPrevious<T>(this IQueryable<T> list, T current)
    {
        try
        {
            return list.TakeWhile(x => !x.Equals(current)).Last();
        }
        catch
        {
            return default(T);
        }
    }
```

Given a Queryable from a data source and a record in it, I just want to get the next and previous values.

Comment: Have you tried with `!=`? I think it might be doing a reference equality..

Comment: You can add indexing to T class and get next and previous object by index. You can check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1869304/determine-the-position-of-an-element-in-an-iqueryable

Comment: this works fine on an array of ints...

Comment: Have you wcheck why it is `null` returned? Your code indicates that `null` is returned only when exception is thrown. Can you paste the message error?

Comment: yes turns out linq to sql doesnt support `skipwhile`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The cause is that `SkipWhile` is not supported by EntityFramework.

First, to use `Skip` or `Take` the collection must be some in order to make EntityFramework support that methods.
So, before method call, you need to have `OrderBy` method:

```
 var orderedList = list.OrderBy(elem => elem.Id) // or other property 
                                                // but need to be rememebered
                                                // because it will be used in furher
```

Then your method for next could be sth like this:

```
public static T GetNext<SomeEntity>(
            this IOrderedQueryable<SomeEntity> list,
            SomeEntity current)
{
    return list.Where(elem => elem.Id > current.Id)
               .FirstOrDefault(); // faster than try-catch
     // assuming, that Id is unique
}
```

That method has one drawback. It is not **generic**. But with a little effort,you can prepare a generic version:

```
public static T GetNext<T>(this IOrderedQueryable<T> list, T current, string orderProperty)
{
    var predicate = string.Format("{0} > @0", orderProperty);
    var propValue = current.GetType()
                           .GetProperty(orderProperty, 
                                        BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance)
                           .GetValue(current);
    return (T)list.Where(predicate, propValue).FirstOrDefault();
                  //where comes from System.Linq.Dynamic
}
```

If you don't like strings as propery names:

```
public static T GetNext<T>(this IOrderedQueryable<T> list, 
                          T current, 
                          Func<T, object> orderProperty)
{
    ..
    var propValue = orderProperty(current);
    ..
}
```

And usage:

```
orderedList.GetNext(current, orderProperty: elem => elem.Id);
```

The generic version relays on **System.Linq.Dynamic** that can be found on [codeplex](https://dynamiclinq.codeplex.com)

I hope it gives you some clue how to make your code work or some idea how to implement it with other approach.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I will get crucified for this solution (because I find it kind of dirty)... but... it works (and it's not using TakeWhile or SkipWhile or DynamicLINQ):

```
public static T GetNext<T>(this IQueryable<T> list, T current)
{
    try
    {
        int idx = 0;
        foreach (T item in list)
        {
            if (!item.Equals(current))
            {
                idx++;
            }
            else
            {
                break;
            }
        }

        return list.Skip(idx).First();
    }
    catch
    {
        return default(T);
    }
}

public static T GetPrevious<T>(this IQueryable<T> list, T current)
{
    try
    {
        int idx = 0;
        foreach (T item in list)
        {
            if (!item.Equals(current))
            {
                idx++;
            }
            else
            {
                break;
            }
        }
        if (idx - 1 == 0)
            return list.First();
        return list.Skip(idx - 1).First();
    }
    catch
    {
        return default(T);
    }
}
```

Comment: i will shoot u wherever i see u for writing this code

Comment: @DarthVader i said: cruzified... not shot. that would be unfair.